# Performance issues with my new SSD drive

Tags: windows-10, ssd, performance, resource-monitor

Since recently I had two Kingston SSD drives, each 240GB (KINGSTON SV300S37A240G). 
I had to change one of them with a bigger one 480GB (KINGSTON SA400S37480G). I cloned the content using Acronis TrueImage 2017 (two partitions, proportionaly sized when cloning).

At first, everything seemed ok, but after a while I started noticing a strange problem. At some random intervals (maybe every 5-10 minutes), the system will stop responding for 2-3 seconds, when i can do nothing (can't change active window, cant open windows start menu...nothing). After couple of seconds everything goes to normal. I opened Resource Monitor and I noticed 2 lines on the disk resource useage graph, one green and one blue that goes to 100% while the system is not responing). Screenshot attached.

I think i have a good configuration which allowed me to work without any problems (IntelCore i7-4770@3.4GHz, Gygabyte Z87P-D3, 16GB DDR3 RAM) but now these interruptions seriously affect the work flow and frustrate me. Sometimes they happen when i'm just coding in a text editor, or when i try to move a file froma one golder to another, some trivial actions that should not be resource intensive

Can someone help me or give me some directiion how to solve this problem? Im using Win10 Home edition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this was an HDD I'd say "it's faulty... stop everything and backup now." That's textbook HDD failure right there. But an SSD doing this? ::scratches his head:: Insufficient power maybe? I'd still backup any critical data pronto.

Comment: SSDs do not consune a great deal of power and would not fail this way if it were a power issue. It sounds to me more like a corrupt filesystem - id force a check (offline) of all filesystems